# В частности - ставить ли запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

Люди добрые! Как обстоят дела с обособлением вводных слов и конструкций с "в частности"?
Примеров несколько.
Он налажен в США и Азии (в частности в Китае). 
Возможно, бывают очень специфические задачи, требующие применения более дорогих материалов (в частности НПК «Суперметалл» изготавливает оборудование для стекольной промышленности из платины и платиновых сплавов), но они находятся за рамками данной статьи.
В частности, тантал обладает исключительной стойкостью к серной кислоте во всех диапазонах её концентраций при рабочих температурах вплоть до её кипения (а это почти 300 градусов).

Answer (score 1):

ПРАВИЛЬНО:

Он налажен в США и Азии (в частности, в Китае).

Возможно, бывают очень специфические задачи, требующие применения более дорогих материалов (в частности, НПК «Суперметалл» изготавливает...).

В частности, тантал обладает исключительной стойкостью...

ДРУГИЕ ПРИМЕРЫ

1. Вводное слово в начале и середине предложения обособляется: В частности, я не знал вовсе польского языка. На этой основе,  в частности, решаются следующие задачи.
2. Вводное слово в роли присоединительного союза не отделяется от обособленных членов: Речь эта, и в частности приведенное место ее, чрезвычайно запомнились. Все надежды возлагались на будущее, а в частности на Кедровскую дачу. Но зато значительно ослабел интерес к внешнему миру, в частности к книгам.
3. Вводное слово внутри скобок обособляется: Эта проблема проявляется при  тестировании знаний по ряду дисциплин (в частности, по предметам гуманитарного, социально-экономического и общественно-политического циклов).
4. Необособленное обстоятельство: Поучительное замечание не относилось ни к кому в частности Он совершенно неожиданно прервал их, не обращаясь в частности ни к кому.
5. Вообще и в частности (не обособляется)
   Против промышленности вообще и против железной промышленности в частности я ничего не имею.

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Comment: Еще по теме: все-таки не могу понять, обособляется ли "в частности" в данном случае? Во-вторых, по стойкости к агрессивным средам (в частности к серной кислоте) хастеллои также превосходят титан.

Comment: То, что стоит в скобках, нужно рассматривать как отдельное сообщение, поэтому ставим запятую: (в частности, к серной кислоте). Вводное слово стоит в начале сообщения, заключенного в скобки.

Answer (score 0):

"В частности" - вводное слово, обособляется.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm

§99. Вводные слова и словосочетания

п.1.2 и п.5

Comment: Я в интернете искала. Оно когда обособляется, когда нет. Иногда обособляется вся конструкция. И еще Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина пишет, что вводные слова "в частности" и "например" не обособляются, если они стоят в начале уточняющего члена предложения. Что ж мне - не верить? Или здесь не тот случай? ))

Comment: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm

§99. Вводные слова и словосочетания

п.1.2 и п.5

Comment: Так а здесь получается не присоединительный оборот?

Comment: Во всех ваших предложениях оборот "в частности" обособляется. Никаких присоединительных оборотов у вас нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробую поверить. Я ведь изначально тоже хотела выделить запятыми.

Comment: У вас то, что в скобках, и есть обособленный оборот. Если бы вместо скобок были запятые, то после "в частности" запятой бы не было, а в скобках она обязательна.